# Training a Machine Learning model on selected parts of DataFrame in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, dataframe, pyspark

I need to run a Random Forest on a dataset. The dataset is in a DataFrame organised as follows:

```
training_set_all = sc.parallelize([
    ['u1', 1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.0],
    ['u1', 0, 0.5, 0.1, 0.0],
    ['u2', 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8],
    ['u3', 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6],
    ['u2', 0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.4],
    ...
]).toDF(('status', 'user', 'product', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3'))
```

Basically there is a `user`, the class - target variable - (1 or 0) and then three numerical float features. In practice every user has its own training set and it is all included in a single DataFrame.

I need to train the mode on a user by user basis, so that from this `training_set_all` I select the part related to user *u1*, train the model, then go to *u2* and do the same and so on for all users.

I could potentially solve by running a for loop on the users, filter the training set for those rows belonging to user and then train on them. But I'd gladly avoid for loops as they don't seem a good element in a Spark programming model.

The [model](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html) requires a LabeledPoint containing (class, feature) and it requires 5 arguments, like the number of trees.

So, I was trying a map-reduceByKey approach as in (mind that I need to pass to `LabeledPoint`)

```
training_set_all \
    .map(lambda row: (row[0], LabeledPoint(row[1], [row[2], row[3], row[4]]))) \
    .reduceByKey(RandomForest.trainClassifier)
```

This clearly fails because I am not feeding the classifier with all the required parameters.

So in order to pass them I tried this:

```
def train():
    return RandomForest.trainClassifier(data, 2, {}, 3)

stuff = training_set_all \
    .map(lambda row: (row[0], LabeledPoint(row[1], [row[3], row[4], row[5]]))) \
    .reduceByKey(train)
```

This fails with error

> Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or
>   reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations
>   and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other
>   transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() *
>   x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action
>   cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more
>   information, see SPARK-5063.

which is very vocal about what's wrong.

How would I apply the model selectively on that part of the training set pertaining to user, and without using a for loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do here Martina. Can you try to explain what do you think your code should do ?

Comment: Code should train model on user u1, then u2 and so on, so using the rows in dataframe belonging to one user at a time.

Comment: you can apply the classifier on the whole DataFrame. There seems to be some serious programming issues here nevertheless without being candescent.

Comment: Try to read this page here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-ensembles.html#examples

Comment: Great, I'm trying to do that, but I cannot train the model on the full dataset as it contains is a training set per each user and I'm trying to do that. Every user has its own training set.

Comment: How much data per user are we talking about?

Comment: Sorry, that point wasn't very clear. I can't even imagine how can a user have his own training set and random forest.

Comment: What is your target variable ?

Comment: @zero323 It's just a collection of training sets, per user. Imagine a list of training sets, I need to classify new data for each of them separately. Every user has different numbers of training samples, but we're talking big numbers. I want to know if I can avoid looping with filtering and training one by one.

Comment: The target is the second element, I called it class but now edited question for nomenclature clarity.

Comment: I saw the edit thanks. Unfortunately, you can't use an RDD inside a transformation of another RDD but if the number of users is restricted and small, you might be able to hack it with broadcast variable. What do you think @zero323 ?

Comment: @eliasah I don't see it. If _big numbers_ are big enough to justify RDD then looping over users is probably the best you can get. If not then Scikit + Joblib could be a better choice.